# Why does my Jquery ajax POST not work in my asp.net web application?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-ajax

The follow jQuery works just fine on a existing asp.net website. I converted it to a asp.net web application and the follow code is no longer working. There is no compile error on the client and it seems to fire just fine. I get the success alert but the Case.aspx/DOFE_update function never appears to run. Here is the weird part if I change the url to sumtingwong.aspx/DOFE_update it obviously fails because the url does not exists but if I change the url to Case.aspx/sumtingwong is does not fail even thought that method on the page does not exist. The spoon does not exist. There must be a glitch in the matrix.

```
 $(function () {
      $("[id=textboxDOFE]").change(function () {

            var DOFE = $(this).val();
            var CaseID = $('[id=CaseID]').val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Case.aspx/DOFE_update",
                data: '{"CaseID":' + CaseID + ', "DOFE":"' + DOFE + '"}',
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                async: false,
                error: function (request) {
                    alert(request.responseText);
                },
                success: function (response) {
                        alert("success");
                }           
            });
        });
    });
```

The code in the Case.aspx.vb file:

```
<WebMethod()>
<ScriptMethod()>
Public Shared Function DOFE_update(CaseID As Integer, DOFE As String) As Integer

    If IsDate(DOFE) Then
        Dim stringCommand As String = "UPDATE dbo.Cases SET DOFE=@DOFE, lockedDOFE=1 WHERE CaseID=@CaseID;"
        Using con As New Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("myconnectionstring").ConnectionString)
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(stringCommand, con)
            cmd.CommandType = Data.CommandType.Text
            With cmd.Parameters
                .AddWithValue("@CaseID", CaseID)
                .AddWithValue("@DOFE", IIf(DOFE = "", System.DBNull.Value, DOFE))
            End With
            con.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
        Return 1
    Else
        Return 0
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm an idiot and have a bad memory. Never mind, I ask this question over a year ago when I originally create the asp.net website.

In the RouteConfig.vb file I commented out this line:

settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent

Not sure what that line is accomplishing or if the site needs it but it causes jQuery AJAX to not work.